# How to get a boolean based on http request status code in Angular 11

Tags: angular, http, boolean

I´m really lost in Angular 11 between all possibilities : `Observable`, `Promise`, `Subscribe`...

I would like just from a get api call a boolean response base on status code.
This call is just to check if the token is already correct to redirect or not the user.

This is one of attempt:

```
export class AuthGuard implements CanActivate {
   constructor(private authService: AuthService, private router: Router, private userService: UserService ) {}
   async canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot) {
    if ( route.url.toString() === 'modifyPassword' ) {
      const resp = this.userService.canModifyPassword( route.queryParams.username, route.queryParams.token );
    } else {
      //
    }
  }
} 

export class UserService {
    constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient) {}
    
    canModifyPassword( username: string, token: string ): Observable<boolean> {
      return this.httpClient.get<HttpResponse<boolean>>(`${API_URL}/users/public/verify/${username}/${token}` );
  }

}
```

Someone has got the easiest and standardest solution in Angular 11 ?

Comment: WebService return value true or only 200 without a response?

Comment: @Den I would like `resp` get true or false.

Comment: yes, but this call ${API_URL}/users/public/verify/${username}/${token} what is his return body?

Comment: @Den, it does not return a body, I need to get the status to return a boolean. 200 = true, else = false;

Answer (score 0):

[According to the Angular docs](https://angular.io/guide/http#reading-the-full-response), you can read the full response by adding `{ observe: 'response' }` to your `get()` method options object.

In your case, that would look like,

```
this.httpClient.get<HttpResponse<boolean>>(`${API_URL}/users/public/verify/${username}/${token}`, { observe: 'response' });
```

This will return an observable of type [HttpResponse](https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpResponse) instead of just the body.

Then you can access the status code with `response.status`.

Comment: That´s a good way, but can you do a complete response including the boolean response and async based on my code ?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way, IMO, is to convert a promise and await, like so:

```
 const resp = await this.userService.canModifyPassword( route.queryParams.username, route.queryParams.token ).toPromise();
    
console.log('got a response of', resp);
```

Answer (score 0):

I found finally a response.
It is based on Promise like @E.Maggini response.

```
export class AuthGuard implements CanActivate {
   constructor(private authService: AuthService, private router: Router, private userService: UserService ) {}
   async canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot) {
    if ( route.url.toString() === 'modifyPassword' ) {
      const resp = await this.userService.canModifyPassword( route.queryParams.u, route.queryParams.t );
      if ( resp ) {
        return true;
      } else {
        await this.router.navigate(['/notAllowed'], {queryParams: {from: 'modifyPassword'}});
        return false;
      }
    } else {
      //
    }
  }
} 

export class UserService {
    constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient) {}
    
    async canModifyPassword(username: string, token: string): Promise<boolean> {
    return this.httpClient.get<any>(`${API_URL}/users/public/verify/${username}/${token}`).toPromise().then(
      data => {
        console.debug(data); // is null 
        return true;
      }).catch(err => {
        console.error(err);
        return false;
    });
  }

}
```

Comment: I dont love using Promise with Angular. Why you not use `catchError`? view this link https://www.pluralsight.com/guides/handling-exceptions-using-the-angular-httpclient#module-rethrowinghttpexceptions